# how php remote debugging works?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have a php webserver setup running in a remote website; lets call it remote.com
Have the wamp installed in local windows machine ( localhost ) and did the necessary xdebug configuration and netbeans installed. Now my doubts are:

1. My IP is not static IP but dynamic one. So specifying this in the remote server's php.ini will work?
2. To debug the php file which resides in the remote server, should I have the same exact copy of source file be available in localhost too? What will happen if there is small changes, lines mismatch etc.
3. What happens in the background technically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Putting a debugger on a live site is a REALLY bad idea!  It'll reduce script performance and expose a lot of information that could prove useful to hackers.

Comment: @GordonM But thats what remote debugging is all about right? Or am I missing anything. Please give me some usecases where remote debugging is helpful.

Comment: Remote debugging is fine on a server that isn't exposed to the general public, such as a firewalled development or staging server.  If the general public can access it then sooner or later soemone will try to attack it.  If you open remote debugging ports you're just making their lives easier.  Plus the debugger will add overhead.